# Build Java program with Japanese comments ( error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8)

Tags: svn, ant, utf-8, javac, java

I'm trying to build an open source Java program, [Smart-GS](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/smart-gs/scm/svn/commits/907), which contains Japanese comments. Javac gives me these messages:

```
[javac] /home/vagrant/smart-gs/trunk/src/com/hexidec/ekit/GSHTMLEditor.java:618: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
    [javac]                     // TODO �����������ꂽ catch �u���b�N
    [javac]
```

Now, assuming that the author can compile the program, where is my UTF8 problem coming from? I'm doing this, in an Ubuntu VM:

1. sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk subversion
2. svn checkout http://svn.sourceforge.jp/svnroot/smart-gs/
3. cd smart-gs/trunk; build

Solutions I see for this kind of problem suggest opening files in text editors and saving with different settings, but perhaps there is a better solution here. (FWIW, I don't speak Japanese...)

EDIT

Working solution is:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setup the enviroment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with -Dfile.encoding=(Name of the encoding in the file. )

so on linux and OSX

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=JIS"
```

or

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=SHIFT-JIS"
```

In the event that fails you could always try to strip out the comments from the file using something along the lines of:

grep -v "^[ ]*//" /home/vagrant/smart-gs/trunk/src/com/hexidec/ekit/GSHTMLEditor.java > /home/vagrant/smart-gs/trunk/src/com/hexidec/ekit/GSHTMLEditor.java

Comment: Ok, that's looking good. Error message now shows the garbled Japanese like `/* B!)FB!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)xB!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!) */`. How do I find the actual encoding?

Comment: Hmm, none of the options in this list worked: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Edited my answer to provide another suggestion.

Comment: @DamianNikodem Your grep will remove entire lines with comments, not only the comments, and also all lines with double slashes in string literals.

Comment: @KarolS Yep, thats completely true, Had to look at the code again Fixed the grep.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'd really like to understand what the actual problem is here though. Somehow the file is being interpreted by Javac with the wrong encoding. How can I find out what encoding it has, and therefore tell Javac what encoding it should be?

Comment: @SteveBennett Use `chardet` or `enca`, or just open the file in a web browser and twiddle the encoding option to see what works.

Comment: @Karols I looked at the file and automatic detection first identifies it as UTF8, and then if that is ruled out then it appears to be Shift-JIS, although it neither seem to be accepted by javac 

Steve,  that's the exact issue the file contains an encoding, and is not of a format which can self-identify the encoding, the majority of the document is in he first code-page of pretty much every 8-bit encoding in existence which dosn't help the situation much.

Comment: Why bother trying to find the *correct* encoding when it is about comments that should be ignored anyway? Using an encoding like `ISO-8859-1`  where every byte value has a corresponding character can’t fail with “unmappable character” when reading source files. The comments will be wrong then but that doesn’t matter as long as the actual code is interpreted right.

Comment: @holger it appears we have a winner :P

Comment: Hooray, that worked. [well, the build still failed, but not for that reason]. Want to make that an answer so I can accept it?